# how to create two separate projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, subdomain

I have shared hosting(godaddy).
I have subdomain "car".
I need create 2 project. in the project root 1 project in subdomain 2 project.

www.site.ru - project first.
www.car.site.ru = project second.

How do this?

but I have added to the root of your project and project car has stopped working.

in iis I do not have access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be easily done by creating the subdomain. Just create the subdomain and install the app which you want to use in the project. You can upload files to your subdomain, the same way you do for your main domain.

Comment: so kind and worth, and the subdomain works fine, but when I put in the root of all stops working

Answer (score 0):

As i know you should a subdomain and assign a separate web application to it.

Like:
www.site.ru     ==> MySite
www.car.site.ru ==> CarSite

This could be however limited by your hosting plan to have only one web application.

Comment: may be in my web config file to specify the folder to car to work with other Web config